# LightBox wont pop up ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightbox

I don't know why it was just loading I had wait for few minutes but it wasn't working or it wasn't popping up. I don't know what's wrong I just followed [this link](http://jfcaiceo.github.io/react-lightbox-component/).

Here is the code

```
if(ext === "PNG" || ext === "jpg") {
var images = 
  [
    {
      src: `http://localhost:8933/files/${form.Name}`,
      title: form.Name,
    }
  ]
    return (
         <Lightbox images={images} 
                    showImageModifiers={false}
                    />

    )
}
```

and this is what it my output on the website it has to pop up instead of having the spinner below it.

[image]

Comment: What is it outputting? Is that not what you expect? You need to say what the desired behavior is. Please don't ask to not be downvoted, instead read the help section on how to ask good questions.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney click the link it has to pop up like that but mine does  was just spinner

Comment: i think you missed out to include lightbox's css into your application, and thats causing the issue. Please provide some more proper code for us to help you.

Comment: im sorry @JefreeSujit where can I get the css ? I thought when I installed it on npm it automatically have the lightbox css, Im so new to this

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out to include lightbox's css into your application, and thats causing the issue

Here is the source repo for [react-lightbox-component](https://github.com/jfcaiceo/react-lightbox-component). Try to access the sass files from the assets under the `node_modules` folder to your application's sass code.

I assume this will be the path for the sass files: `node_modules/react-lightbox-component/assets/sass/images.sass`

Comment: so i should changed the  `var Lightbox = require('react-lightbox-component').Lightbox;` ?

Comment: yes, if you still use es5 syntax, for es6 you would use `import {Lightbox} from 'react-lightbox-component'`;

Comment: I m telling you again, you need to import the sass file of the component into your application's sass file for it to work properly.